# Android E-mail Attachment Dynamic with file extenstion

Tags: android, file, email, attachment, dynamic

How do you attach a file that is in the memory for example a string, with a file extension of .txt etc. I have tried storing the string the internel memory and then attaching it and I can't get it to work either though I would much prefer I solution to my first problem.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("plain/text");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data.enw", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(export_text.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(new File("data.enw").toString()));
    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"MyEmail"});
    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment");
    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Import the attachment");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "E-mail"));
```

[Edit] The code below works however it requires an SD Card. Is there a better way of doing it.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("plain/text");

File data = null;

try {
data = File.createTempFile("data", ".enw");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(data);
out.write(export_text.getBytes());
out.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(data));
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"MyEmail"});
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Attachment");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Import the attachment");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "E-mail"));
```